# Sparse column vs. Indirection

Tags: mysql

As I understand, MySQL doesn't have any special `SPARSE COLUMN` directive, and any question like this is purely situational, so I'm wondering if there is a good rule of thumb for when to use a sparse column vs. when to create another table.

As a specific example, I have a table called `Lessons`.  We want to add a `lesProgramNumber`, but this will only apply to about 10% of all lessons at any given time (it will be NULL for the other 90%).  We could avoid a lot of `NULL` data by having a `LessonsProgramNumber` table very easily, but then this requires an additional JOIN at times.  Is there an easy way to make a choice about what I need?  What if `Lessons` only has 500 rows?  What if it has 500 million?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

InnoDB's COMPACT row format (which is the default) does not store anything when a column is NULL; it only stores non-null columns.  It just skips that column in the on-disk row storage.  So the cost of sparse columns is not so bad.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-physical-record.html

Comment: Just to clarify: the only concern about a sparse column is space, not time, right?  What if we're using MyISAM?  What if we want the column to be a boolean but still not take up space (I assume `'0'` still takes space, so we'd have to swap between `NULL` and `1`..

Comment: Don't use MyISAM.  Really.  Regarding 0/1, right, 0 is a value so it takes space.  Use TINYINT so it only takes 1 byte.

Comment: I don't have a choice, this is a legacy table that's using `MyISAM` .. we might consider trying to change it but it's not really up to me.  I would use a `tinyint(1)`, but swapping between `NULL` and `1` could save some space.

Comment: Fair enough, I understand the difficulty of changing storage engine, because it can have other unintended effects.  Read http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_MyISAM to understand how MyISAM stores nulls.

Comment: FYI , given link is broken.

Comment: @ManirajSS, yes, they discontinued the MySQL Forge. Some content was copied other places, but I haven't found the same MyISAM internals document. Here's the archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20120523081418/http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_MyISAM